# Set last week's Monday as defaul in dropwdown in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown which I have to populate with the last 5 Mondays, but I need to set the Monday of the previos week set as default

I have the following code to create a list of the last 5 Mondays

```
Public Sub GetMondays()
    'populate the dateselection with the last 5 mondays to show the week starting
    Dim dtMondays As New DataTable()
    dtMondays.Columns.Add("Date")
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim count As Integer
    While (count < 5)
        Dim Day As DateTime = Today.AddDays(-i)
        If Day.DayOfWeek = 1 Then
            DateSelection.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(Day, "dd/MMM/yyyy"), Day))
            count = count + 1
        End If
        i += 1
    End While
End Sub
```

If today is the 26th of May 2014 I would see the 10th of May and the following full list in the dropdown:

```
19/05/2014 > Displayed
12/05/2014
05/05/2014
28/04/2014
21/04/2014
```

If today is the 27th of May 2014 I would see the 10th of May and the following full list in the dropdown:

```
26/05/2014 > Displayed
19/05/2014 > This one should be displayed
12/05/2014
05/05/2014
28/04/2014
```

What I need is to keep the order as per above, have the previous Monday selected in the dropdown as per above.

Any ideas on how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare week number for today and the first item in the list

```
GetMondays()

Dim c As Calendar = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar
If c.GetWeekOfYear(Today, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday) _
   = c.GetWeekOfYear(DateSelection.Items(0).Text, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday) Then
     DateSelection.SelectedIndex = 1
 Else
     DateSelection.SelectedIndex = 0
 End If
```

if week number is the same (e.g. "27/05/2014" and "26/05/2014" will have same week number) then change selection to the second item (SelectedIndex = 1)

P.S.

You can also try more efficient code to populate the list. It does not need to enumerate each day in 4 weeks to find Mondays. You only need to find last Monday and then you can use AddDays(-7) to get a week back.

```
'Dim count As Integer
'While (count < 5)
'    Dim Day As DateTime = (Today.AddDays(1)).AddDays(-i) 
'    If Day.DayOfWeek = 1 Then
'        'DateSelection.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(Day, "dd/MMM/yyyy"), Day))
'        Console.WriteLine(Format(Day, "dd/MMM/yyyy"), Day)
'        count = count + 1
'    End If
'    i += 1
'End While

Dim Day As Date = Today.AddDays(-(Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday))
For count As Integer = 1 To 4
    DateSelection.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(Day, "dd/MMM/yyyy"), Day))
    Day = Day.AddDays(-7)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Smirnov for the solution and thanks for the added improved code. Much appreciated